# Python UT - Mocking a function local veriable

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a function as follows

### Function

```
   def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3): 
       # all the method code....
       parent = arg1.get_item(larg1)
       if larg2 not in parent.children:
            # do stuff
```

I want to mock `parent` in the method, so that when I call `parent.children` i can return empty list `[]`. 
Thoughts?

### Already tried

```
@patch('foo.bar.foo')
def test_my_test(self, mock_method)
    parent = mocked_method.return_value
    mocked_method.parent.children = []
```

** This mocks the entire method.

Answer (score 0):

Mock the `arg1.get_item` method and return your expected value. If you want to return an object,you can also mock it as such.

### fix

```
@mock.patch(
        'foo.bar.foo.get_item',
        mock.Mock(return_value=mock.Mock(children=[]))
    )
```